# uswsusp package has gone in Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, suspend, hibernate

`uswsusp`, which is used for hibernation, [presents](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=uswsusp) latest in the old stable, but has gone in Bullseye (the current stable). What is it replaced with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn’t replaced: [its removal request](https://bugs.debian.org/954061) says

> It's dead upstream and also no longer properly maintained in Debian.
> Nowadays, the kernel provided suspend and hibernate functionality is
> preferred and should be used instead.

In Debian 11, you should use the suspend features in your desktop environment, or [`systemctl suspend`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#suspend) and siblings:

- `systemctl suspend` instead of `s2ram`;
- `systemctl hibernate` instead of `s2disk`;
- `systemctl hybrid-sleep` instead of `s2both`.

The only missing tool from `uswsusp`, as far as I can determine, is `swap-offset` which is used to determine the offset of a swap file’s header in the containing block device. You can obtain this information with `filefrag -v` — the offset is the first value shown in the “physical offset” column for the first extent.

systemd additionally supports “suspend-then-hibernate” mode, which suspends the system, and then hibernates it after a configurable delay.

Comment: How do you configure the systemd delay from suspend to hibernate?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.conf.html#HibernateDelaySec=